# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalTypeMapper'

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I created **Asp.net Core 2** project.

[image]

Select **MVC with Individual User Accounts**.

I changed ConnectionStrings in appsettings.json and set Sql server parameters.
Now i run an application and create one user.

*It's running work successfully.*

Now, I created one table.
eg: table name: setting

Now i want to add model from existing database.

I used below commands in **package manage console**.

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=JAMES-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DATABASE_NAME;User id=sa; Password=PASSWORD;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data`

It gives an **error:**

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalTypeMapper' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory'.

If i create MVC project with No Authentication and try then it is working properly.

My installed packages are:

[image]

Comment: For ASP.NET Core 2.0, you need additional NuGets for scaffolding. In particular here, you're likely missing something like `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design`. ASP.NET Core 2.1 does not require these packages, and in fact will choke on them if they're included. Based on the screenshot, it looks like you're using 2.0, but if you actually are using 2.1, then alternatively, check for packages like these and remove them.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I remove `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design` from installed packages. and use command but still faced same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrong package is installed for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` for `AspNetCore 2.0`, you need version `2.0.3`, the one you have referenced is for `AspNetCore 2.1`....`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools @ 2.0.3` is correct

Comment: I replaced `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.0 to 2.0.3` It's worked completely.

Comment: and? what happened?

Comment: Working successfully, Thanks